# ResourceLoader not working reliably, switching randomly between languages

Tags: .net, uwp, localization

When setting in my app the Language with   ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride it will only affect some locale settings:

```
ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "en-US";
Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();


XAML => x:UID => Working fine after a restart
C# => with ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("MyStringFromResources") not working realbily.
```

For example:es-ES (default & system) MyStringFromResources = "clima", en-US = "weather". User is switching to en-US.
ViewModel => working fine. result ist "climate"

User pressing button and raising an event=> wrong output. result is "clima".

But here is the catch: It's random. Restarting the app: It's working. Start again: not working. Is it related ot the UI thread having another locale?

```
Debug.WriteLine(ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride); => en-US
Debug.WriteLine(Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("MyStringFromResources")); => returns string for es-ES
```

Every time the wrong language is loaded, the following QualifierValues are stored in the ResourceContext:

```
var loader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView();
var qualvalues = loader.QualifierValues;
Debug.WriteLine(qualvalues["language"]);
```

The output is (when the wrong lang is loaded):

> ;en-US;es-ES

Somehow there is an *empty* language qualifier added to the ResourceContext.QualifierValues. But why is it random?

Comment: If you use `GetForCurrentView` you get the resource loader connected to the UI thread you are on. So this would be an issue in case of multiple views. Is that your scenario?